# how to insert marker's position in firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am inserting the marker in google map[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqxjj.jpg) as I moved in google map.But I also want to insert the marker's latitude and longitude.I have applied some code but it is inserting only the initial latitude and longitude. please help me out to insert the multiple latitude and longitude for the same key in firebase

I want to add locations under "l" tag

Comment: since firebase is based on noSql i.e key value pair it will overwrite the data if key already exists in database. try passing timestamp as a key for lat lng data

Comment: Thank you @ Ashish Pardhiye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using to update a location with a `Map` and you are using the same key, in stead of adding a new value, your are overwriting the existing one. With other words, in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one.

If you want to to have different values for latitude and longitude for a single location, i suggest you use the `push()` method, which generates a unique key for each new latitude and longitude. This unique ids are ordered by default in ascending order.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you still think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!